# Getting an error even using the same compiler version (Visual Code)

Tags: chainlink, compiler, solidity-0.6.x, visual-studio-code

I made a contract using Remix and it's working perfectly. When I create a project in Visual Code (in order to make a DApp) I'm getting this error when I import a source of Chainlink:

[image]

If I compile that contract in Remix with the same compiler (version 0.6.6) I don't get any error. May anyone help me with this question? I'm getting crazy.

You can check the full code of my contract here:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/master/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

/// @title 
/// @author
contract generator is VRFConsumerBase {
    // Researcher information
    struct Researcher {
        string name;
        bool registered;
        string solution;
    }
    mapping(uint => Researcher) researchers;
    
    // Instance information
    struct Instance {
        uint id;
        string instance;
        uint date;
    }
    Instance[] instances;
    
    // Relation between researches and their instances
    struct Linked {
        uint[] idInstances;
    }
    mapping(uint => Linked) links;
    
    // General variables
    address owner;
    uint nonce;
    
    // VRF variables
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    uint256 public randomResult;
    
    // MAX-3SAT variables
    uint[] symbols;  
    uint p;
    uint q;
    uint clausesLength;
    
    /// @notice Main constructor
    constructor(uint _p, uint _q) 
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9, // VRF Coordinator
            0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088  // LINK Token
        ) public {
        
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
        p = _p;
        q = _q;
        owner = msg.sender;
        nonce = 0;
        clausesLength = 3;
    }
    
    // ---------------------------------- General functions ----------------------------------
    
    /// @notice Registers a new Researcher 
    function regResearcher(string memory _name, string memory _solution, uint _orcid) public {
        require(!researchers[_orcid].registered, "Researcher is already registered");
        Researcher memory newResearcher = Researcher(_name, true, _solution);
        researchers[_orcid] = newResearcher;
    }
    
    /// @notice Gets Researcher information
    function getResearcherInformation(uint _orcid) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
        require(researchers[_orcid].registered, "You must be registered");
        return (links[_orcid].idInstances);
    }
    
    /// @notice Generates a random number within an interval
    /// @param _interval upper index of the (open) interval of the random value
    /// @dev now, msg.sender and nonce are the timestamp of the block, who made the call and an incremental number respectively
    /// @return The number generated
    function random(uint _interval) internal returns (uint) {
        uint randNumber = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender, nonce))) % _interval;
        nonce++;
        return randNumber;
    }
   
    // ---------------------------------- VRF functions ----------------------------------
    
    function getRandomNumber(uint256 userProvidedSeed) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) > fee, "Not enough LINK, fill contract with faucet");
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userProvidedSeed);
    }
    
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness.mod(100);
    }
    
    // ------------------------------- MAX-3SAT functions --------------------------------
    
    /// @notice Generates a new Instance 
    function createInstance() public {
        string memory fi = ""; // empty initialitation
        symbols.push(symbols.length);
        for(uint i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            if(random(100) < p) // [0, 99] < p
                symbols.push(symbols.length);  
        
        fi = conca(fi, createClause(), "", "");
        while(random(100) < q){ // [0, 99] < q
            for(uint i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                if(random(100) < p) // [0, 99] < p
                    symbols.push(symbols.length);  
            
            fi = conca(fi, " ∧ ", createClause(), ""); 
        }
        Instance memory newInstance = Instance(instances.length, fi, now);
        instances.push(newInstance);
    }
    
    // @notice Creates a new clause
    function createClause() internal returns (string memory) {
        string memory c = "(";
        for(uint i = 0; i < clausesLength; i++){
            if(random(100) < 50) // [0, 9] < 5 => 50% probability
                c = conca(c, "x", intToString(symbols[random(symbols.length)]), "");
            else
                c = conca(c, "¬", "x", intToString(symbols[random(symbols.length)]));
            // We need to add a new symbol in every iteration except for the last one
            if(i < clausesLength-1)
                c = conca(c, " ∨ ", "", "");
        }
        c = conca(c, ")", "", "");
        return c;
    }

    function conca(string memory s1, string memory s2, string memory s3, string memory s4) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(s1, s2, s3, s4));
    }
   
    // -------------------------------- Support functions --------------------------------
    
    function getSymbolArray() public view returns (uint[] memory){
       return symbols;
    }
   
    function getInstance(uint _index) public view returns (uint, string memory, uint){
        return (instances[_index].id, instances[_index].instance, instances[_index].date);
    }
    
    function intToString(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len - 1;
        while (_i != 0) {
            bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
            _i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code doesn't support fetching GitHub files natively, it is only the Remix's feature. If you want to import the files, you need to download them locally.

Answer (score 2):

Your import statement should look like this:

`import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";`

You also need to use NPM or Yarn to download the Chainlink packages locally.